# script of google map is called everytime when page loads

Tags: ionic4

script src(api key) of google map should loaded only once when page get loaded

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=apikey" async= "true"></script>
```

**.ts file**

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'googleMap';
    console.log(script,'script')
    if (this.apiKey) {
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' +
        this.apiKey;
        console.log(script.src,'script.src')
    }
    else {
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=';
    }
    document.head.appendChild(script);
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What do you have the snippet in the .ts file for if you are already placing it manually in the main html file?

Try removing that.

If not then please give some more details about where your `const script =...` snippet is actually in the app. It must be in a place where it's getting called more than once?

## Update

Based on your comments you saying that you have removed the script example that you posted but it is still including it multiple times.

This sounds like you haven't put you `<script>` tag within your `<head>` tag. If it is inside something that repeats then it would repeat.

If this doesn't solve your problem then please reword your question to include better snippets and more clarity of what your current set up is, otherwise we can only guess at what it could be.

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=apikey" async= "true"></script>                                                                                                     
     if I am adding only in index.html file, then also its repeating again again